# Intersystems Cache not generating data with Populate

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-iris

Hello) I'm having a problem generating data in IRES, I'm using %Populate class inheritance, as well as the Popsec and VALUELIST properties. Here is my class:

```
Class User.Car Extends (%Persistent, %Populate)
{

/// Description
Property Brand As %String(POPSPEC = "ValueList("",Ford,Lada,BMW,Kia"")", VALUELIST = ",Ford,Lada,BMW,Kia");

/// Description
Property Name As %String(POPSPEC = "ValueList("",Focus,M6,Rio,Octavio"")", VALUELIST = ",Focus,M6,Rio,Octavio");

/// Description
Property Type As %String(POPSPEC = "ValueList("",SUV,sedan,liftback"")", VALUELIST = ",SUV,sedan,liftback");

/// Description
Property foundationDate As %DateTime(POPSPEC = "Date()");

/// Description
Property maxSpeed As %Numeric(POPSPEC = "Float(150,200,0)");

/// Description
Property enginePower As %Numeric(POPSPEC = "Float(50,400,0)");

/// Description
Relationship companyCar As User.Company [ Cardinality = one, Inverse = carsCompany ];

/// Description
Index companyCarIndex On companyCar;

Storage Default
{
<Data name="CarDefaultData">
<Value name="1">
<Value>%%CLASSNAME</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="2">
<Value>Name</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="3">
<Value>Type</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="4">
<Value>Brand</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="5">
<Value>foundationDate</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="6">
<Value>maxSpeed</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="7">
<Value>enginePower</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="8">
<Value>company</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="9">
<Value>Names</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="10">
<Value>companyCar</Value>
</Value>
</Data>
<DataLocation>^User.CarD</DataLocation>
<DefaultData>CarDefaultData</DefaultData>
<ExtentSize>20</ExtentSize>
<IdLocation>^User.CarD</IdLocation>
<IndexLocation>^User.CarI</IndexLocation>
<Property name="%%CLASSNAME">
<AverageFieldSize>1</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>100.0000%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="%%ID">
<AverageFieldSize>1.55</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>1</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="Brand">
<AverageFieldSize>5</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>16.6667%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="Name">
<AverageFieldSize>12</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>9.0909%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="Type">
<AverageFieldSize>4.7</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>33.3333%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="companyCar">
<AverageFieldSize>1.9</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>16.6667%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="enginePower">
<AverageFieldSize>2.9</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>6.6667%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="foundationDate">
<AverageFieldSize>19</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>12.5000%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<Property name="maxSpeed">
<AverageFieldSize>3</AverageFieldSize>
<Selectivity>7.1429%</Selectivity>
</Property>
<SQLMap name="IDKEY">
<BlockCount>-4</BlockCount>
</SQLMap>
<SQLMap name="companyCarIndex">
<BlockCount>-4</BlockCount>
</SQLMap>
<StreamLocation>^User.CarS</StreamLocation>
<Type>%Storage.Persistent</Type>
}
}
```

But when I enter the command Do ##class(User.Car).Populate(5) in the terminal, nothing happens and no data is generated.
If anyone knows what could be the problem, I would be very grateful if you could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of comments.  You have

/// Description
Property Brand As %String(POPSPEC = "ValueList("",Ford,Lada,BMW,Kia"")", VALUELIST = ",Ford,Lada,BMW,Kia");

but you don't really need the POPSPEC=""ValueList("",Ford,Lada,BMW,Kia"")"

As by default using %Populate already handles %String fields when a VALUELIST is defined.  To simplify things I would define this

/// Description
Property Brand As %String(VALUELIST = ",Ford,Lada,BMW,Kia");

/// Description
Property Name As %String(VALUELIST = ",Focus,M6,Rio,Octavio");

/// Description
Property Type As %String(VALUELIST = ",SUV,sedan,liftback");

/// Description
Property foundationDate As %DateTime();

/// Description
Property maxSpeed As %Numeric(MINVAL=150,MAXVAL=200,SCALE=0);

/// Description
Property enginePower As %Numeric(MINVAL=50,MAXVAL=400,SCALE=0);

if you look at the method documentation for Populate you'll see

> classmethod Populate(count As %Integer = 10, verbose As %Integer = 0,
> DeferIndices As %Integer = 1, ByRef objects As %Integer = 0, tune As
> %Integer = 1, deterministic As %Integer = 0) as %Integer Creates up to
> count instances an object and stores them in the database. If verbose
> is true, then details are echoed to the console.
>
> If DeferIndices is true, then indices are sorted at the end of the
> operation.
>
> If objects is true, then each object that is created is returned in
> the objects array
>
> If tune is true, then $SYSTEM.SQL.TuneTable is called after the
> instances of the class have been created. If tune>1, then
> $SYSTEM.SQL.TuneTable is also called for any tables projected by
> persistent superclasses of this class
>
> If deterministic is true, then the set of objects produced by
> identical calls to Populate at different times will be identical.
>
> Returns the number of instances successfully created.
>
> For more information refer to The Populate Utility.

so you might consider calling .Populate with the verbose flag.  I believe the primary issue is your POPSPEC on foundationDate as this field is a %DateTime but then you have a POPSPEC that sets this field as just a Date.